# How to convert dates from several formats into one single format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have several different formats of dates in one field.  It looks like this.

```
20200228

12/15/2021

7/6/2020

Oct 29 2017 12:00AM

Oct 31 20

08/01/18
```

How can I get everything standardized as MM/DD/YYYY?

```
20200228 --> 02/28/2020

12/15/2021 --> no change

Oct 31 2017 12:00AM --> 10/31/2017

Oct 31 20 --> 10/31/2017

08/01/18 --> 08/01/2018
```

I tried all kinds of Cast and Convert combinations, but I couldn't get anything to work.  Does anyone out there have a solution for this?  It doesn't have to be one pass in one query.  I'm sure it can be done in several iterations, but I don't know how to tackle it.

Comment: Dates stored as text are rubbish. If you are really aiming at standardization at least aim for YYYY-MM-DD which will sort sensibly. You really ned a true date column. btw: If I enter 04/06/2017 is that April or June? (tip I am not from the USA)  so good luck sorting out the data ambiguities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just try one conversion after another -- but convert to a `date` not to another format.  Here is one idea:

```
select coalesce(try_convert(date, col),
                try_convert(date, col, 100),
                try_convert(date, col, 101),
                try_convert(date, col, 102),
                try_convert(date, col, 107)
               )
```

I'm not sure if this covers all your formats, but it is worth a try.

EDIT:

SQL Server is pretty flexible in reading dates.  The defaults appear to work for your examples:

```
with d as (
      select '20200228' as col union all
      select '12/15/2021' union all
      select '7/6/2020' union all
      select 'Oct 29 2017 12:00AM' union all
      select 'Oct 31 20' union all
      select '08/01/18'
     )
select cast(d.col as date)
from d;
```

The [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/13059) is using SQL Server 2014.  I don't think the handling of casts of dates has changed (although that might have).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm working in a 2008 environment.  I should have mention that in my post.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd create a persisted computed column using a CASE statement with IsDate (available since 2008):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD YourDate_DateTime AS CASE WHEN ISDATE(YourDate) = 1 THEN CAST(YourDate AS DATETIME) ELSE NULL END PERSISTED
GO
```

That way you don't need to constantly perform the calculation every time. Anything that SQL doesn't recognize as being a date will be NULL, but there's really no way around that short of fixing every such value. At least this way you can easily search for NULL values to go fix.

Comment: Thanks Russell.  After some more research, I was leaning towards this idea at the end of the day.  I can't do anything now, but I will try this concept as soon as I get into the office tomorrow morning.  Thanks.

Comment: Obviously, if there's any way to change the front end to some sort of date picker control, it will make your life much easier in the long run!

Answer (score 1):

try this, it will help you--

UPDATE myTable 
SET myDateColumn = CONVERT(DATETIME, myDateColumn, 103)
WHERE ISDATE(myDateColumn) = 0